# Reading packets with NEPacketTunnelProvider without proxy

Tags: ios, swift, macos, networkextension

I would like to inspect packets with [NEPacketTunnelProvider](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nepackettunnelprovider) without a specified proxy. Unfortunately my [readPacketObjects](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nepackettunnelflow/2118343-readpacketobjects) completion handler is never being called and I don't understand why. My regular internet connection stops and Wireshark shows nothing on the new interface obviously and I don't see any of my HTTP connection on en0 either.

Is this possible? [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/76707) suggests it might not be... but Charles Proxy for iOS seems to be able to inspect everything.

My code is below:

```
class TunnelProvider: NEPacketTunnelProvider {
override func startTunnel(options: [String : NSObject]? = nil, completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    os_log("starting tunnel")

    let settings = NEPacketTunnelNetworkSettings(tunnelRemoteAddress: "127.0.0.1")

    settings.tunnelOverheadBytes = 80
    settings.mtu = 1200

    settings.ipv4Settings = NEIPv4Settings(addresses: ["127.0.0.1", "0.0.0.0"], subnetMasks: ["0.0.0.0", "0.0.0.0"]) // all addresses
    settings.ipv4Settings?.includedRoutes = [NEIPv4Route.default()] // all routes
    settings.ipv4Settings?.excludedRoutes = [NEIPv4Route(destinationAddress: "127.0.0.1", subnetMask: "255.255.255.255")] // avoid local routes

    settings.dnsSettings = NEDNSSettings(servers: ["1.1.1.1", "8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"])
    settings.dnsSettings?.matchDomains = [""] // if blank don't use this DNS, use system; if "" then use this

    NSLog("default/included route %@:%@", NEIPv4Route.default().destinationAddress, NEIPv4Route.default().destinationSubnetMask)

    self.setTunnelNetworkSettings(settings) { error in
        if let e = error {
            NSLog("Settings error %@", e.localizedDescription)
            completionHandler(e)
        } else {
            os_log("Settings set without error")

            completionHandler(nil)
        }
    }

    self.readPacketObjects()
}

private func readPacketObjects() {
    NSLog("Inside readPacketObjects %@", self.packetFlow)
    self.packetFlow.readPacketObjects() { packets in
        NSLog("Inside readPacketObjects completionHandler %@", packets)

        self.packetFlow.writePacketObjects(packets)

        self.readPacketObjects()
    }
}
```

Console output

```
default 10:31:03.177424 -0400   tunnel  starting tunnel
default 10:31:03.177796 -0400   tunnel  default/included route 0.0.0.0:0.0.0.0
default 10:31:03.178602 -0400   tunnel  Inside readPacketObjects <NEPacketTunnelFlow: 0x7f9a69d135e0>
default 10:31:03.356006 -0400   tunnel  Settings set without error
```

**Edit 1**
I am able to read packets after modifying `settings.ipv4Settings` to a local address with a more specific subnet mask. However the internet connection is still down and `route get` outputs bad address.

**Edit 2**
I was able to get DNS to work by adding the DNS servers to the excludedRoutes as seen [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/78622). Writing to the packetFlow with no modifications still doesn't enable full routing tho.

Comment: Were you able to make progress on this?

Comment: I'm working on this problem in parallel, so maybe I can catch up to you and we can help each other out? When you use `NETunnelProviderProtocol` from your main application, what do you set as the server address? It looks like a value is required there, so I imagine I'd want to point somewhere on localhost? (Charles uses the value "Charles Proxy" - that doesn't mean much to me. Aren't we using the network extension itself as a proxy?)

Comment: Just an update on this ^ (maybe nobody cares? :P) but I can now replicate the issue. I'll post a solution when I find one.

Comment: @wheresmycookie it isn't really possible without doing translations yourself. You can't just send the packets back into the flow. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117539

Comment: Thanks for the link. Are you still working on this? I can keep you updated if you'd like. Seems like this is definitely possible.

Comment: @wheresmycookie I'd be interesting in your approach. Please share if possible

Comment: With your current NEPacketTunnelNetworkSettings I can only see traffic heading towards 50.17.39.244 (at least on my device). Are you seeing something similar?

Comment: @wheresmycookie I think I can see everything with the code in the developer forum link

Comment: So, when I set settings.ipv4Settings?.excludedRoutes = [] I can see all of the DNS queries, which presumably I can parse and pull out domain names. Otherwise, if I use the values you included, I see essentially nothing. Were you seeing the DNS queries even with the IP addresses in the excluded routes?

Comment: I excluded the DNS addresses so the system could do the routing for me

Comment: I ended up getting this to work. It's essentially a solution involving rebuilding the transport layer in the network layer with raw UDP/TCP sockets.

Comment: That’s what I thought. Not an easy task.

Comment: @wheresmycookie would you be willing to share how you solved this?

Comment: @wheresmycookie same here, can you share your results somewhere? This question pops up everywhere regarding packet tunnel provider, and it's driving me nuts. Three apps have done it – Surge, Proxyman and Charles – yet it's a complete mistery how to do this if you read around. I think you would make a lot of devs happy if you could put a basic implementation on github.